# Как можно избавиться от дублирования в этом участке кода Golang?

Tags: postgresql, golang, методы, рефакторинг

Я новичок желающий писать чистый код, так что не ругайте пожалуйста). Пробовал искать в документации или в открытых репозиториях, но не нашёл как правильно оформлять подобный код.
Так же я слышал, что с SQL запросами лучше не использовать операции на строки. А чем это чревато и как можно решить проблему в данном случае?

Собственно сам код:

```
//EditCustomer берёт новые данные и изменяет значения в таблице.
//Если поле равно "" то не обращать на него внимания.
func (s *Service) EditCustomer(ctx context.Context, item *types.Customer) error {
    sqlBase := "UPDATE customers SET {col} = $1 WHERE id = $2 RETURNING id"
    if item.Name != "" {
        sql := strings.ReplaceAll(sqlBase, "{col}", "name")
        err := s.pool.QueryRow(ctx, sql, item.Name, item.ID).Scan(&item.ID)
        if err == pgx.ErrNoRows {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow No rows:", err)
            return ErrNotFound
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow error:", err)
            return ErrInternal
        }
    }
    if item.Password != "" {
        hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(item.Password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("EditCustomer bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword Error:", err)
            return ErrInternal
        }
        item.Password = string(hash)
        
        sql := strings.ReplaceAll(sqlBase, "{col}", "password")
        err = s.pool.QueryRow(ctx, sql, item.Password, item.ID).Scan(&item.ID)
        if err == pgx.ErrNoRows {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow No rows:", err)
            return ErrNotFound
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow error:", err)
            return ErrInternal
        }
    }
    if item.Address != "" {
        sql := strings.ReplaceAll(sqlBase, "{col}", "address")
        err := s.pool.QueryRow(ctx, sql, item.Address, item.ID).Scan(&item.ID)
        if err == pgx.ErrNoRows {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow No rows:", err)
            return ErrNotFound
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow error:", err)
            return ErrInternal
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

просто вынести все и передать те части, которые меняются

```
func (s *Service) EditCustomer(ctx context.Context, item *types.Customer) error {
    sqlBase := "UPDATE customers SET {col} = $1 WHERE id = $2 RETURNING id"
    
    simplifyFn := func(s *Service, item *types.Customer, item_attr string, replaceName string) error {
        sql := strings.ReplaceAll(sqlBase, "{col}", "name")
        err := s.pool.QueryRow(ctx, sql, item_attr, item.ID).Scan(&item.ID)
        if err == pgx.ErrNoRows {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow No rows:", err)
            return ErrNotFound
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Println("EditCustomer s.pool.QueryRow error:", err)
            return ErrInternal
        }
    }
    
    
    if item.Name != "" {
        err :=  simplifyFn(s, item, item.Name, "name")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    if item.Password != "" {
        hash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(item.Password), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("EditCustomer bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword Error:", err)
            return ErrInternal
        }
        item.Password = string(hash)

        err :=  simplifyFn(s, item, item.Password, "password")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    if item.Address != "" {
        err :=  simplifyFn(s, item, item.Address, "address")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```